# Backbone adding content to current view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm not much familiar with Backbone but I have a project to support which has tiny usages of Backbone. There is a spot in the backbone script of the page:

```
App.Views.Products = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName: "table",

            className : "table table-bordered table-hover data-table",

});
```

Which initializes a view-template and then parse it as a table and renders it to the view. I want to add something just before the table, I have added the following piece to the above code but it does not work, and just adds the content to the very beginning of the table:

```
initialize : function(){
   this.$el.prepend("I have added this content,");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method inserts the specified content as the first child of matched element(s).

In your case you have to use [`.before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method instead:

```
initialize : function(){
   this.$el.before("I have added this content,");
}
```